# Terra raster of mollweide not ovular

Tags: r, sf, terra

I am trying to visualize 3D unit vectors in 2D using R. A globe-to-map projection seemed like a good way to do that but I'm finding the terra package to be very confusing. The data I have is just x,y,z (ihat, jhat, khat) which I convert to longitude and latitude. From here I convert it to the 'sf' 2d data, then use terra to project to a Mollweide shape. However, the projection does not conform to the traditional ovular Mollweide shape. Not only are the heatmap squares out of bounds but they also don't change shape or size to become more triangular in shape the farther from the equator. I don't do any work with cartography so this package may not be the right choice, but I feel like my code is so close to working.

Also, why are the longitude values so large?

Shouldn't it be -180 to 180?

```
library(sf)
library(terra)

plot_flatearth <- function(data) {
  # define mollyweide projection
  proj_type <- "+proj=moll  +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0"
  # project the sf lat lon values to terra w/ proj_type defined above
  proj_pts <- project(vect(data), proj_type)
  # create a raster of a sphere
  r <- rast(nrow = 9, ncol = 18, xmin=-180, xmax = 180, ymin = -90, ymax=90)
  # project the raster onto mollyweide
  r <- project(r, proj_type)
  # define some nice graticules
  grat <- sf::st_graticule(lon=seq(-180,180, 60),
                      lat = seq(-90,90,45),
                      ndiscr = 5000) %>%
                      vect() %>%
                      project(proj_type)
  total <- nrow(data) # just get a count of how many points there are
  # project the data onto the raster with each raster rectangle being composed of the % of total
  obs <- rasterize(proj_pts, r, fun=function(i){length(i)/total*100})
  # plot it
  p <- plot(obs, axes=TRUE, clip = TRUE)
  plot(grat, add=TRUE) # add the graticules
  return(p)
}

# make some lon and lat dummy data
dummy_df <- data.frame(c(runif(4000)*360-180), c(runif(4000)*180 -90))
colnames(dummy_df) <- c('lon', 'lat')
# convert it to sf points
dummy_df_sf <- st_as_sf(dummy_df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs')
fe_plot <- plot_flatearth(dummy_df_sf) #plot function
```

[image]

Comment: This looks fine when I run it - the raster is neatly within the outline. Can you add your versions of `sf` and `terra`, and also say which R environment you are using since its possible its graphic device isn't the same as mine (Linux/ESS/R 4.1.1/sf:1.0.12/terra:1.6.18). I don't get those colours, for example. The large numbers are because you are looking at the projected coordinates. Lines of constant longitude are the curved lines from pole to pole, and they can't be labelled at the edge.

Comment: I am using Windows/Pycharm/R 4.1.3/sf:1.0.12/terra:1.7.23. I think the color differences is likely because of my IDE. I've realized the reason the graticules don't fit the plot is because of the size of the plot window in the IDE - when I drag it wider the plot elongates to fit within the graticules (and looks more ovular). It still does not make the square shaped data change size/shape farther from the equator. Is this normal?

Comment: Well it appears that getting square rasters projected to be not square is not supposed to happen. https://rspatial.org/spatial/6-crs.html#transforming-raster-data